# Angular/Ionic: Keep all text in a separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app using angular/ionic and am wondering if there is a recommended way of keeping ALL the text in a separate file. The idea being, during the testing phase it is quite easy for the content creator to make changes to the text in the app without going in the code.

Comment: Export all text as key value pairs in json file

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

It lets you store all the strings in a single file. In case you need more languages in the future, it is easy to add them without the need of making huge code modifications.

Everything you might need should be found here http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html